# select everything that does not match pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex which gets everything but a specified pattern. I've been trying to use negative lookahead but whenever testing my expression, it never works.

I have files that are of this form:

(garbage info) filename (other garbage).extension
or
[garbage info] filename [other garbage].extension

For example, one of the files is [O2CXDR] report january [77012].pdf or
(XEW7CK) sales commissions (99723).xls

I'm using the regex.h library in C so I believe that it is a POSIX library.

I'm hoping on extracting "filename" and ".extension" so that I can write a script which will the files filename.extension

So far, I have a an expression to select the garbage info with the brackets and the spaces around it but I'm unable to select the rest.

```
\s*(\[|\().*?(\]|\))+\s*
```

and the negative lookahead I tried was:

```
.*(?!(\s*(\[|\().*?(\]|\))+\s*)).*
```

but it's just selecting everything in a single match.

I'm sure that I'm not understanding the lookaheads and lookbehind correctly. What do I have to do to fix my expression? Could somebody explain how they work since I'm a bit lost. Thanks!

Comment: edited the post. I'm using the POSIX regex.h C library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't specified a regex engine, I'll target a subset that can use the tags `\K`, `\G`, and `\A` (like *PCRE*).

The following uses a combination of match resets (`\K`), [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3600709), and start of match (without start of string) `\G(?!\A)`, further explained below:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/bKfrZp/1)

<sub>Note: remove empty matches</sub>

```
\s*[[(].*?[])]\s*\K|\G(?!\A)(?:(?!\s*[[(].*?[])]\s*).)+
```

- Match one of the following:

  - Option 1:

    - `\s*` Match any whitespace any number of times
    - `[[(]` Match either `[` or `(`
    - `.*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible (lazy matching)
    - `[])]` Match either `]` or `)`
    - `\s*` Match any whitespace any number of times
    - `\K` Reset match - sets the given position in the regex as the new *start* of the match. This means that nothing preceding this tag will be captured in the overall match.
  - Option 2:

    - `\G(?!\A)` Match only at the starting point of the search or position of the previous successful match end, but not at the start of the string.
    - `(?:(?!\s*[[(].*?[])]\s*).)+` Tempered greedy token matching anything more than once except the negative lookahead pattern (which is the same as the first option).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, as simple as

```
^(?:\(([^)]*)\)\s*([^(\r\n]*?)\s*\(([^)]*)\)|\[([^\]]*)\]\s*([^(\r\n]*?)\s*\[([^\]]*)\])\.(.*)$
```

we could extract those values.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/caUMK5/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

If you don't need all of those capturing groups, we'd then simply remove those that we wouldn't want:

```
^(?:\([^)]*\)\s*([^(\r\n]*?)\s*\([^)]*\)|\[[^\]]*\]\s*([^(\r\n]*?)\s*\[[^\]]*\])\.(.*)$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/52mTi1/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat input_file
(garbage info) filename (other garbage).extension
 (garbage info)filename(other garbage).extension
(garbage info)file name(other garbage).extension
[garbage info] filename [other garbage].extension
 [garbage info]filename[other garbage].extension
[garbage info]file name[other garbage].extension
$ sed -re 's/^\s*(\([^\)]*\)|\[[^]]*\])\s*(.*\S)\s*(\([^\)]*\)|\[[^]]*\])(\..*)$/\2\4/' input_file
filename.extension
filename.extension
file name.extension
filename.extension
filename.extension
file name.extension
```